# share a js-class between .vue files

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

Back in my day we had this crazy thing called include or import or whatever. It meant that you wrote some code in one file and then reused it in different files. So you would create a class in file x, include this file in another file y and instantiate an object from this. Basically this means, that you were able to call a function form file y even though it is written in file x.

How can something like this be done in `vue.js`? I understand that the new hip way to do it is called "components api". Online I only found really convoluted examples that had some coupling with the dom, something I don't need.

Or should I use `mixins`? `Mixins` seem to be working at least, but they have a scope problem.

Here is the file I want to share (x.vue):

```
<script>
export default
{
    data ()
    {
        return {
            a: 'test'
        }
    }
    ,mounted ()
    {
        
    }
    ,methods:
    {
        test ()
        {
            console.log( "test : " + this.a );
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

The y.vue:

```
  <script>
    import x from './x.vue'
    
    export default {
        
        name:"whatever"
        
        ,components:
        {
            x
        }
        ,mounted()
        {
            x.a = "it is working";
            x.test();
        }
    }
    </script>
```

The web-browser tells me that a is not a function. does anyone know where the mistake is? Or should i just create a js class and try to import that?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Added an answer of how it should look like with `mixins`. As you stated in another comment, this wouldn´t fix your request to call it like `x.test()`, but from my experience you learn fast how to avoid name your function in a way they could match with others :D

Comment: Added an edit to my answer. Something that could be matching with your needs.

Comment: maybe i really am on oltimer already, but using something better than naming conventions to fix such collisions has been solved decades ago. going back to that method seems crazy, but if there is no other way, i don't seem to have a choice. thanks for the help.

Comment: Have you read the edit of my answer? This is something like you wanted. In your case you could call `this.$super(x).sayHello();`.

Comment: yes, i have, but this only changes the way the function is called. collisions can still happen.

Comment: Hope you find a workaround. Good luck with your project!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Mixins are not useful in this case as there cannot be more than one instance of a mixin. It is like copy and pastes the code from the mixin into the other file.

Sharing code between Vue components can be done by many savers with standard js classes. All that is needed is that the class is declared with `export default class`.

Comment: @0x6368656174 this is the correct answer. sneed harder

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're looking for mixins:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html

They Allow you to share functions, data, hooks and all other from another file.

Comment: i know about mixins, but i would like to have that "x." before a function call. like "x.test()". with mixins this would beocem "test()" and if i have a test function in my y.vue file, i am going to have a bad time. or should i prefix all the functions like in good old c?

Answer (score 0):

This would be an approach in your case.

**mixins.js:**

```
export default {
    methods: {
        sayHello () {
            console.log( "test : " + this.a);
        }
    }
};
```

**component.vue:**

```
<script>
    import mixins from "@/path/to/mixins/mixins";

    export default {
      name: "whatever",
      mixins: [mixins],
      data ()
      {
          return {
              a: 'HELLO'
          }
      },
      created() {
        this.sayHello();
      }
    }
</script>
```

For further information: [Mixins](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html)

---

**EDIT: Looks like there is something that matches your needs!**

mixins.js:

```
export default {
    name: 'Mixin',
    methods: {
        sayHello() {
            console.log("Hello")
        }
    }
}
```

component.js:

```
export default {
    name: 'whatever',
    mixins: [Mixin],
    created() {
      this.$super(Mixin).sayHello();
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT2: As you requested, an simple example to pass arguments.**

mixins.js:

```
export default {
    methods: {
        sayHello(foo, bar) {
            console.log(foo + bar)
        }
    }
}
```

component.js:

```
export default {
    name: 'whatever',
    mixins: [Mixin],
    data () {
        return {
            baz: 'Say'
        }
    },
    created() {
      this.sayHello(this.baz, " Hello");
    }
}
```

Comment: i know about mixins, but i would like to have that "mixins." before a function call. like "mixins.sayHello()". with mixins this would become "this.sayHello()" and if i have a sayHello function in my component.vue file, i am going to have a bad time. or should i prefix all the functions like in good old c?

Comment: Read your other comment and replied to your question with a comment. But yes, you should prefix them to clearify their usage. For example: If you outsource `sayHello()` to a mixin, it´s because you will use it in other components too, so it would be rational to call it `globalSayHello()`.

Comment: no mixins don't work because you cannot pass arguments with those function calls. vue really is aweful. why are people using it? has someone created a big project with it once? seems like it falls apart as soon as the code grows out of the prototyping phase.

Comment: Sure you can pass arguments, i´m using it this way right now. I have a mixin function where I build a a filter array for a data table and to do that, I just pass the whole API response to the function in mixins. It is even possible to pass arguments inside of mixins between methods. I'll edit that to my answer.

Comment: consider a mixin where a variable is set and an async call is made to a server. from a vue component the mixin variable is set to "1" and the async server call is executed. if the vue component is calling the mixin again (before the server response) and sets the variable to "2" and an async server call is executed. if the first server call is returned the variable is not "1" anymore, but "2". if the mixin were an object this would not be the case as there are 2 different instances and the first would have the variable set to "1" until the destructor is called. did not notice it at first myself

Comment: also, i cannot downvote anybody here. i think i need more points.

Comment: @pls_help What you discribed is how you NOT should use `vue.js`. For state management you should use `vuex`, which would solve problems like this. Please, the problem isn´t `vue.js` lacking of logic, you just don´t know enough about it.

Comment: @pls_help "has someone created a big project with it once?". As this is a question I will give you a answer: Yes. You may know [fontawesome.com](https://fontawesome.com/), to name only one.

Comment: you can use a class by declaring it as "export default class". no need for something like vuex.

Comment: @pls_help As I already said: For state management you should use `vuex`. If you don´t use `vuex` for state management and don´t use `mixins` for reused functions I don´t know why you even use `vue.js`.

Comment: because i use laravel and - contrary to what i believed - these vue/angular/react memes are not going to go away so soon. goddamn web components, really hoped they would be a bigger hit. also classes have nothing to do with state management. why always use more and more libraries. makes everything so complicated. classes are already here.

Comment: State-Management isn´t a library, it´s part of managing data in web app´s.